# Audio over displayport suddenly stopped working

Tags: audio, external-display, displayport, microsoft-surface-pro

I used to connect my Surface Pro 3 via DisplayPort to my LG display, playing the sound though the LG. Today when I tried to connect the Surface it didn't worked. I checked if somehow the default output changed, however it's all correct. The speakers of the display work (checked by connecting the Surface via the 3.5mm audio-jack to the display).

Actually I have no idea what the problem could be, that's why I am asking you now.

Michael

Comment: `The boxes of the display work` By boxes you mean speakers? `checked by connecting the Surface with an extra audio-cable to the display` You mean connecting the 3.5mm audio jacks on them? If so you might want to check the audio input source setting on your monitor.

Comment: Sry, I am not a native speaker. But yeah you are right! Also the input source on my monitor is set to DP.

Comment: That's weird. You shouldn't get sound from the speakers when you test with the 3.5mm audio jack in that case. (Wait do you mean `audio input source` or `video input source`? Coz I meant `audio input source`)

Comment: Sry that I missed to say that I switched the input when I connected the 3.5mm audio jack. I just wanted to check if the speakers are working. And yes, I always meant the audio input source.